# Android Multiple switches

Tags: java, android, if-statement, switch-statement

I've got some problems with the switch-struktur in Android.

I want to create 3 switches which are able to change the background color of my Relative Layout.

Now I'm at the point, that I the switches can change the background color,
but even 1 of 3 are working, the others don't.

How could I make all of them working?
At the moment I use if-struktures:

```
@Override
    //Teil2
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {                //Action für Switches

    RelativeLayout lay1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.lay1);


    if (switch1.isChecked()){                                                                   //isChecked() => Wenn "an"

        TextView label2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.label2);                                  //Label label2 auswählen
        label2.setText("On");
                                                                                                //Layout aus activity_main.xml, verknüpft über die id. (Wenn in main "Relative layout", dann hier auch
        lay1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff95e1ff"));                                 //Farbe muss geparst werden, damit Hexadezimal Zahlen gehen

    }else{
        TextView label2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.label2);
        label2.setText("Off");

        lay1.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    }


    if (switch2.isChecked()){

        TextView label3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.label3);
        label3.setText("On");

        lay1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

    }else{
        TextView label3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.label3);
        label3.setText("Off");

        lay1.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    }


    if (switch3.isChecked()){

        TextView label4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.label4);
        label4.setText("On");

        lay1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

    }else{
        TextView label4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.label4);
        label4.setText("Off");

        lay1.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    }


}
```

Thanks for you Help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe when you used swithes you forgot about

break;

statement. This stops the flow in the case block.
Please pass your code with switches.

Answer (score 0):

Switch-Case would not help or simplify your code as your variables state only contains 2 options true or false,

An equivalent switch-statement would be (for switch1)

```
switch(switch1.isChecked()){
  case true:
    TextView label2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.label2);                                  
    label2.setText("On");
    lay1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff95e1ff"));  
    break;

  case false: 
    TextView label2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.label2);
    label2.setText("Off");
    lay1.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    break;

}
```